# Getting this error while using jupyter notebook "Could not build wheels for psutil, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects. "

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am new to python and have installed python 3.11 and in vs code i have installed the python extension. But when i try to create a jupyter notebook and execute a code it shows me this dialog

[image]

I click on install and then i get this error

[image]

Not able to know what exactly it means. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance

Comment: Downgraded to 3.10.8 and now it is working. Not sure why it didnt run with the latest 3.11 version

Answer (score 0):

Update: I was able to manually fix the issue by following the description in my links provided

**Step 1: Manually download the psutil wheel**

A slightly older version than current (*psutil-5.9.0* instead of *psutil-5.9.3*) is available for download [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#psutil)

I have used `psutil-5.9.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl` running Windows 11 64 bit.

**Step 2: Install psutil manually**

Inside your (virtual) Python environment install the just downloaded psutil file using `pip install`

e.g.:
`pip install "C:\your\path\psutil-5.9.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl"`

**Step 3: Retry installation of ipykernel**

Jupyter does not work because ipykernel is missing. Install it using
`pip install ipykernel`

**Step 4: Ensure you have selected the correct interpreter**

In VS Code finally double check that you are working with the correct interpreter where you have just installed ipykernel
`>Python: Select Interpreter`

After those steps Jupyter is now working for me running Python 3.11.

---

Anyway the root cause of this issue seems to be an incompatibility during the automatic install prcocess:

Refer to:
[windows 10 - python 3.11.0 - error installing psutil #2165](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/2165) or
[Failed to install ipykernel (psutil building wheel not run successfully) on python 3.11 #2163](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/issues/2163)